# godot 3.5.2 жалуется на то что в 7 строчке надо добавить ")" или "," не вижу где, помогите тупице

Tags: godot

```
extends Node2D
onready var playerPos1 = $Position_Player_1
onready var playerPos2 = $Position_Player_2
func _ready():
    var player1 = preload("res://Player_1.tscn").instance()
    player1.set_name(Str(get_tree().get_network_unique_id())
    player1.set_network_master(get_tree().get_network_unique
    player1.global_transform = playerPos1.global_transform
    add_child(player1)
    
    var player2 = preload("res://Player_1.tscn").instance()
    player2.set_name(Str(Singleton.user_id)
    player2.set_network_master(Singleton.user_id)
    player2.global_transform = playerPos2.global_transform
    add_child(player2)
```

Comment: `player1.set_network_master(get_tree().get_network_unique` -> `player1.set_network_master(get_tree().get_network_unique)` и на 11 строке аналогично. Поставьте себе нормальную IDE, что бы синтаксис подсвечивала

Comment: Это не питон или джава это годот, там нет IDE,

Comment: Для годота же вроде есть плагин для vscode. Такие проблемы должен подсвечивать по идее. @SwaD Там же по ссылке для С++ настроки, а не для gdscript.

Comment: @user7860670 Похоже на то. Удалю ссылку. В конце концов, кто ищет, тот найдет...

Comment: В годоте прекрасная встроенная IDE с подсветкой, даже незакрытую скобочку красненьким раскрашивает https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyXma.png